# Display Role name (ID) and Display Role Name

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming, user-roles

This question has been askled before but no answers given.
I want to display the ROLE NAME as well as ROLE ID

As, far as Role ID is concerned, I am successfully displaying that using:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
     
     $user = wp_get_current_user(); 
     $roles =  $user->roles; 

     $_SESSION['roles']=$roles[0];

        return $roles; }
```

But I want to display the Display Role Name.
As shown in the figure below, I am able to print **senior_manager** but cant get to print **Senior Manager**

[image]

Comment: start from here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/displaying-user-role-name/

Comment: Thnaks. I tried this but it is just returning the Role ID

Answer (score 1):

We just have to replace `_` with a `space` and `capitalize`. We can use `str_replace()` and `ucwords()`.

```
<?php
/**
* is_user_logged_in()
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/
*/
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ):

  /**
  * auth_redirect()
  * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/auth_redirect/
  */
  auth_redirect();
else:

  /**
  * wp_get_current_user()
  * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/
  */
  if ( wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] !== '' ):
    echo ucwords( str_replace( '_', ' ', wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] ) );
  else:
    echo "Not available";
  endif;
endif; ?>
```

---

### Learn more

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this can be done and works fine. However, I was just looking for inbuilt function in WP which can give access to it .